# MVC website calling WCF is better or MVC calling database operation directly is better

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, wcf, dependency-injection

We need to develop a website that can be browsed from desktop browser. We also need to develop an android application for the same website. We are thinking of using ASP.NET MVC using C#, Microsoft SQL Server and Windows Communication Foundation, Linq To Entity with Repository Framework.

WCF will access database using Linq to Entity using Repository Framework and return JSON.

**Question 1** 
 Android application will call WCF service. Are we thinking correct?

**Question 2**
ASP.NET MVC website will call WCF service. Making ASP.NET MVC application call WCF service is better or ASP.NET application directly communicating with database without having WCF in the middle is better?

My idea is to use WCF only for android application and make ASP.NET MVC interact directly with database using linq to entity framework using repository pattern without WCF in the middle. Will this be a good approach?

**Question 3** 
 If ASP.NET MVC website will call WCF service, where do i need to implement DI. I think it must be between repository framework and WCF service and DI will have nothing to do between ASP.NET MVC and WCF. Right?

This may be a simple question but I want to know how others are doing if they have same kind of requirement. Like website and android application.  I am not familiar with DI and how to use it. I have been reading about DI and am not quite getting it. So I wanted to know where DI will exist?

Comment: Usually Android just calls a web-service that replies in a JSON format. As long as the web service can return a JSON format(as per wikipedia WCF have it on .net 3.5) you can program with any structure you prefer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your Android app cannot call your database directly, so you need a service in between. This can be WCF or another popular option is ASP.NET Web API.
2. You should not let your MVC app communicate with the database indirectly through a WCF service, unless this is really needed (because of security or organizational concerns for instance), because this extra layer of indirection costs performance. There is a lot of overhead in communicating with WCF that just doesn't seem necessarily.
3. If you decide to let your MVC app call into a WCF service, both the MVC and WCF application get their own [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This means that they each have their own DI configuration and their own way of injecting dependencies. They might share a lot, but this doesn't have to be.

I expect you might found my answer disturbing. You are probably concerned with the development overhead of having a both a WCF service and MVC app that both communicate to the database, instead of having only a WCF service that talks to the database.

This doesn't have to be the case though. In fact, this SHOULDNOT be the case. When you're doing that, you're doing things wrong. A WCF service itself should be nothing more than a really thin layer on top of your business layer. The same business layer that your MVC app uses. In fact, when applying the correct abstractions, you would be able to swap your MVC app from using the database to using the WCF service in a matter of minutes.

You can do this by placing your business operations behind a generic abstraction and use a message-based architecture. Your WCF service (or Web API) can in that case simply excepts those messages and forwards them to the business layer. If you do this correctly, you'll find out that you can write your WCF service or Web API service in such way that they become maintenance free, which means: you won't have to change them when the system grows; when new business operations are added to the system.

I advice you to read the following articles:

- [Meanwhile... on the command side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)
- [Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)
- [Writing Highly Maintainable WCF Services](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95).

If you're -after reading those articles- in doubt about how to implement this, take a look at the [Highly Maintainable Web Services project](https://solidservices.codeplex.com/). This is a reference architecture application that shows how to apply these concepts using both WCF and Web API.

Comment: 2nd point: "because of security concerns" Can you give some examples? Does this mean an application is less secure without an additional web service layer?

Comment: @Rookian: If that database is maintained by another team, that team should not give you direct access to its database. This forces tight coupling on their data model. In that case it's more an organizational constraint. If that database is not located within your organization's domain, but somewhere across the country, you should probably not expose that database directly to the internet. That's a security concern. In those cases you'd be better of hiding that database behind a web service abstraction.